# How to hide lines with .plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I do not want to connect points with lines. I know that for that I can use scatter. But, scatter does not work after plot.

So, basically I have to lists of points. The points from the first list I do want to connect with lines while the points from the second list should not be connect with lines.

How can one achieve it in matplotlib?

This is what I have tried:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xys[:,0], xys[:,1], marker='o', color='g')

# WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE?
#plt.plot(xys_bad[:,0], xys_bad[:,1], color='r', linewidth=0.0, markersize = 10.0)
plt.scatter(xys_bad[:,0], xys_bad[:,1], color='r')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As describe in [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle) you should use the `'None'` `linestyle`:

```
plt.plot(xys_bad[:,0], xys_bad[:,1], color='r', linestyle='None', markersize = 10.0)
```

Comment: so weird that `linestyle=None` does not work. It must be a string.

Comment: For me, this removes the line altogether. How do I keep the points?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer: Maybe your forgot to add the `marker` property.

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer I used `marker = "."` and that worked. (following s.ouchenes advice)